# How to remove certain file directories from .gitignore about Git

Tags: git

I performed the following operations as an example

```
echo '.temp' >> .gitignore
echo '.cache' >> .gitignore
```

Now I want to remove it from `.gitignore`

What should I do？

Comment: `vi .gitignore` and remove them.

Comment: Edit the file `.gitignore`, save it, and then commit the changes

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have solve the question

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to do this using script.
Try something like :

```
sed -e s/deletethis//g -i .gitignore
```

It use sed to replace "deletethis" by "" in the file .gitignore.

(this solution has not been tested)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).